# javascript- Selecting multiple checkbox and copying the data

Tags: javascript

I can't figure this out and have been trying for hours. I have a JSP that looks like below:

[image]

My goal is to tick the selected checkbox and click on `copy selected url` button and it should be able to copy all the unique URL,in order. Then,I could paste it anywhere I want.

This is my JSP page:

```
<table class="filesTbl">
    <tr>
        <th width="1%">
            Checkbox
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
             No
        </th>
        <th width="20%">
            File Name
        </th>
        <th width="50%">
            Unique URL
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
            Edit
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
            Copy
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
            Email
        </th>

    </tr>

<%
    //need to input logic to populate data on each row

    int counter=0;
    int tally=0;

    String[] split = request.getParameter("nodeID").split(",",0);
    for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){

        long file=Long.parseLong(split[i]);

        List files = fileFacade.list_items(file);
        for (Iterator rstltr = files.iterator(); rstltr.hasNext();) {
            Fmedia fv = (Fmedia) rstltr.next();
            Node nd = nodeFacade.get(fv.getNodeid(), false);
            // Fmedia fm = fileFacade.get_file(fv.getNodeid());



            int count = 0;
            count++;
            long fileid= nd.getNodeid();

      SettingsFacadeLocal settingFacade = (SettingsFacadeLocal)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/settings");
        String redirectURL = settingFacade.get("SERVER_URL").getAtval();
        //declare a timestamp for unique URL
        // String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
        // String hash = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(timeStamp);

        SecureRandom secureRandom=new SecureRandom();
        byte[] token = new byte[12];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(token);
        String hash= new BigInteger(1, token).toString(12);





%>


    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="5%">

            <script>

                function checkRow(element){
                    try {



                        var checked = $(element).is(':checked');
                        var rowCount = $(element).attr('rowcount');
                        var classRow = 'rowOut';

                        if(checked==true){
                           <%=nd.getNodeid()%>

                        }


                        if(rowCount % 2 == 1){
                            classRow = "rowOver";
                        }



                    }catch(err){
                        alert(err);
                    }
                }



                function copymultiplelink() {
                    var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                    if(selectedFiles.length < 1 ){
                        alert("Please select at least one file.");
                        return false;
                    }

                    var $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                    $fileChecks.each(function() {
                        alert(<%out.print(nd.getNodeid());%>);
                    });




                }
            </script>

            <!--Display Checkbox   -->
            <input type="checkbox" class="fileCheck" id="<%=tally=tally+1%>" onclick="checkRow(this)" />&nbsp;


        </td>

        <td>
            <!--Display No   -->
            <% counter=counter+1;
                out.print(counter);

            %>


        </td>
        <td width="28%">

            <!-- Display Filename   -->
            <%=nd.getNodedesc()%>



        </td>
        <td width="100%">
            <!-- Display URL -->


            <%=redirectURL+"/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?f0="+nd.getNodeid()+"&ts="+hash%>
            <%

                fileFacade.insert_url(nd.getNodeid(),"f0="+nd.getNodeid()+"&ts="+hash);

                //fileFacade.insert_url(nd.getNodeid(),"{syscont url}/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?{url});

            %>


        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- Display EDIT/DEL -->

        </td>
        <td> <!-- Display COPY feature -->

            <input type="button" value="Copy URL" onclick="copyURL('<%=redirectURL+"/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?f0="+nd.getNodeid()+"&ts="+hash%>')">

        </td>


    </tr>

    </tbody>


<%}}
%>


    <script>
        function copyURL(url) {
            var copyText = url;
            var el = document.createElement('textarea');
            el.value = copyText;
            el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
            el.style = {
                position: 'absolute',
                left: '-9999px'
            };
            document.body.appendChild(el);
            el.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
            document.body.removeChild(el);
            alert("You have copied the URL");
        }
    </script>





</table>




</div>

<!--Copy button to copy multiple links -->

<div class="wrapper">
<input type="button" value="Copy Selected URL" onclick="copymultiplelink()">
</div>
<style>


    .wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 90%;
        left: 5%;
    }

</style>


</body>
```

I wrote a javascript function `copymultiplelink()` to be able to detect each URl tied to each checkbox but apparently, I could only grab one of the files but not more than one if i checked two.

Any idea how I could solve this dilemma?

I appreciate it.

EDIT:

This is my way:

```
  <script>




                function copymultiplelink() {

                    var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                    if(selectedFiles.length < 1 ){
                        alert("Please select at least one file.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var filesList = [];
                    var $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                    $fileChecks.each(function() {
                        filesList.push($(this).val());
                    });

                    alert("You have copied " + filesList.length+ " URL");
                    copyURL(filesList);

                }
            </script>

            <!--Display Checkbox   -->
            <input type="checkbox" class="fileCheck" id="<%=tally=tally+1%>" value="<%=redirectURL+"/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?f0="+nd.getNodeid()+"&ts="+hash%>"  />&nbsp;


        </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maintain an array of checked values and update it accordingly in the `checkRow` function. In your `copymultiplelink` function, you can iterate through the array and append the `redirectURI` of each entry to an empty string and execute `copyURL(<GENERATED STRING>)`

Define a variable called `var checkedRowArray = []`.
Change your `checkRow` function to

```
function checkRow(element) {
  try {
    var checked = $(element).is(':checked');
    var rowCount = $(element).attr('rowcount');
    var classRow = 'rowOut';
    var nodeId = <%=nd.getNodeid()%>;
    if (checked == true) {
      checkedRowArray.push(nodeId);
    } else {
      checkedRowArray = checkedRowArray.filter(function(x) {
        x !== nodeId;
      })
    }

    if (rowCount % 2 == 1) {
      classRow = "rowOver";
    }
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
}
```

The `checkedRowArray` variable now has the record of all the nodes that are selected.
`copymultiplelink` function:

```
function copymultiplelink () {
  var copiedURLs = '';
  for (var i in checkedRowArray) {
    var node = checkedRowArray[i];
    copiedURLs += `${<GET THE REDIRECT URL FROM NODEID>}\n`;
  }
  copyURL(copiedURLs);
}
```

Comment: How does it look like, I am not sure what you mean.?

Comment: Please help,I couldn't figure this for hours.

Comment: I did it differently, would you like to see my answer? I didn't use checkrow function

Comment: The only problem with my solution is the alert popup the number of times i select the checkbox

Comment: Yeah you must have a `alert` call somewhere in the function which you can get rid of I guess.